# Can I safely use "not" instead of words with negative prefixes?

Tags: negation, prefixes

Sometimes it's difficult for me as a learner to remember the negative word as a new word with prefix. For example, the negative of **pleasant** is **unpleasant**.

Can I *safely* use **not** instead? I'm not intending to not learn new words, but I want to prevent something awkward happening if, for example, I want to say the negative word for **honest** and mistakenly I say *unhonest* instead of **dishonest**.

Is it always safe to use 'not' for words I want to negate, or there are particular words where it isn't safe?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Often the "un" form is stronger than the not form.

```
               happy      neutral       sad
more happy <----------|------|------|--------->less happy
```

Unhappy is often roughly the same as "sad", but "not happy" could include "neutral" and "sad"

And there are things to watch out for:

> You look not happy.

> You don't look happy.

Only the second of these is idiomatic.

While you can be understood with "not ...", developing fluency means being confident with the un- in- dis- and other negating prefixes.

In short, it is unsafe to default to 'not' as your meaning could easily be misconstrued. It's also not a good habit to form for your long term progress.

Comment: Yeah, +1, even though it's not a prefix form, consider the idiom, "not bad", which is often more emphatic than just, "good".

Comment: The advice here is excellent, but i don't think this actually answers the question

Comment: "not happy" is also often used to annoyance, mild anger, disappointment

Comment: @kojiro Indeed.  Or even "not good", which is pretty commonly used to emphasize a particularly *bad* situation.

Comment: Good answer.  In other words, to say a proposition is not true is logically different from saying the opposite of the proposition is true.  And good point about idioms as well.

Comment: We also use the “not” forms to indicate sarcasm or emphasis where the usual form wouldn’t. But without any special tone to indicate which was meant, I’d assume the neutral-inclusive case.

Comment: I would rollback the edit unless James K is satisfied with it. @TCooper Edits should improve a post: fix typos, formatting, sometimes clarify a question if the author has done so in a comment. Not respond in the author's name because of a single comment stating that the question has not been answered. The 28 upvotes obviously disagree with that statement.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I don’t have the reputation to decide whether or not the comment is published, just recommended it. Not sure if if author or another approved it. I do personally think it improves the answer though, if only as a summarization of the already great answer

Comment: @TCooper I should have checked the review queues before opening my big mouth. James K had approved the edit. So, everyone's happy now :)

Answer (score 7):

There are some words that can take several different negative prefixes, and the different compound words have different meanings.  Typically, one is the simple antonym and the others have narrower meanings.  *Non-* typically means “something other than,” *dis-* “the opposite of, in a bad way,” *a-* “not having,” and *anti-* “opposed to,” but *un-* can be particularly flexible.  Which words allow which prefixes is completely arbitrary.  Some examples include:

Non-moral (not a moral issue), versus immoral (worthy of moral condemnation) versus amoral (a person who does not believe in right or wrong, an action taken without regard for morality, or something that lacks any moral dimension)

Uninterested (not interested) versus disinterested (having no conflict of interest).  Watch out, though: some native speakers use these as synonyms, and others consider that an error

Nonfunctional (not functional) versus dysfunctional (functions in an awful or abusive way)—but note that dysfunction is a noun that means a failure to function, malfunction is either a noun or verb that means to function incorrectly, and there is no such word as *nonfunction or *malfunctional. (But there is *malfunctioning*.)

Nonsexual (content that is not sexual), versus asexual (an organism without sexual differentiation, or a person without a sex drive) versus antisexual (opposed to sex)

Unconcerted (not concerted, unplanned, not an organized effort) versus disconcerted (confused, perturbed)

Non-sensitive (not painful to touch) versus insensitive (not sensitive to other people’s feelings, callous)

Sometimes the base word and a compound that reverses it have evolved so much that they no longer are even opposites. The words *ingenuous*, *disingenuous* and *ingenue* have diverged to the point that they no longer have anything to do with each other.  They all derive from the same word meaning “honest, plain-speaking, high-minded” (or literally, possessing “inborn” virtue), which came to mean naïve and honest to a fault, but *ingenuous* got mixed up with *ingenious*, an *ingenue* is an innocent young woman, and *disingenuous* means pretending not to understand or know things that you really do. An example is when antisemites disingenuously pretend that the word *antisemitic* means something other than hating Jews and act like it refers to the Semitic language group. The people who say that know better and are trolling.

That was also an example of how *in-* sometimes means the-opposite-of, but often is a fossilized Latin preposition instead.  An ingenious person is clever and inventive, not the opposite of a genius.

Similarly, *unbarred* means not blocked or prohibited, but *disbarred* comes from a different root and means that someone was banned from the legal profession for unethical conduct.  However, an unfrocked Catholic is a (rarely-used word for a) defrocked priest, not a layperson, and unrobed is a rarely-used synonym for disrobed.

In front of some ethnonyms, such as *American*, *Christian*, *Muslim* or so on, you can add negative prefixes with very different connotations.  *Non-Jewish* is a neutral term meaning “not Jewish,” *Anti-Muslim* is a disparaging term meaning “bigoted against Muslims,” and *un-Christian* means “hypocritically antithetical to the values of Christianity.” The exact connotations vary.

Or to get really obscure, *anti-establishment* means trying to topple the powers that be, *non-establishment* means holding different views, but *disestablishment* has a very narrow meaning: abolishing what the U.S. Constitution calls a “law regarding an establishment of religion,” and revoking the special legal status of a state religion.  There’s even a word *anti­dis­est­ab­lish­ment­ar­ian­ism*, the movement of people opposed to disestablishing the state religion, although most appearances of it are in lists of the longest English words.

Comment: So, we will be hearing anti-establishmentarians soon with regard to Afghanistan?

Comment: @Lambie I suppose anti**dis**establishmentarian could be a very polite way to describe the Taliban.

Comment: The word “amoral” is used less often to describe a person or their beliefs, and more often to describe an action or decision—that is, that this is an action or decision that isn’t a moral question, that the various options are equally moral (or equally amoral, or equally immoral) and the choice has to be made, or judged, on other grounds.

Comment: Also, it might be worth noting that *antidisestablishmentarianism* was originally opposed specifically to the disestablishment of the Church of England.

Comment: @KRyan I considered that, but then thought, and the Church of Scotland, and the Church in Wales, and then whether my answer really needed to be longer.

Comment: Whoops. [my mistake]

Comment: Don't forget the _in-_ prefix, just to make things more confusing.

Comment: @Bobson I guess insensitive versus non-sensitive would be a genuine example of that, but it’s much more common to see words from Latin where *in-* is a fossilized preposition.

Comment: @KRyan I’ve edited the discussion of *amoral* to mention that it has more than one meaning. I don’t have good statistics on the different meanings of *amoral*, but most dictionaries use something like “having no concern for whether something is right or wrong” as the first definition, and “being outside or beyond the moral order” as a second or third definition. That normally means they consider the primary definition more common, and that was my impression too.

Answer (score 4):

There are some cases where *not X* and *unX* aren't equivalent, for example *unbelievable* and *not believable*:

> This person is unbelievable. (amazing, astonishing)

> This person is not believable. (not trustworthy)

at least one case where *X* and *inX* share the same meaning (from @abligh's comment):

> Flammable
> Inflammable

same with *X* and *irX*:

> Regardless
> [Irregardless](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/irregardless)

These are all corner cases, though. I guess using *not X* would work in most situations, at least for you to be understood.

Many valid points in the three other answers so far, feel free to unaccept mine and pick another one!

Comment: ... and sometimes they mean the same thing (flammable, inflammable)

Comment: @abligh That’s because *inflammable* came from the same Latin word as *inflame,* and the *in-* in *inflame* comes from a preposition like *on* in “on fire.” However, some people incorrectly thought the *in-* had the same effect as in “incorrectly”—or at least safety authorities were afraid they would and cause an accident. So, starting in the 1980s, warning labels were required to say “flammable,” and that really did confuse a lot of people.

Comment: @abligh Doctors, I guess, figured that other doctors and nurses would know better than to think *inflammable* meant “no risk of flammation.”

Comment: Note that irregardless is often considered incorrect in standard English

Comment: @tim Yes, this word is non standard and controversial indeed.

Answer (score 2):

Also, regarding the negative sentences such as,

- "It was not an unpleasant journey" *vs.*
- "It was a pleasant journey"

The meanings are not equivalent. The first sentence means that there were no incidents, etc. to spoil the experience while the second emphasizes that the person making the journey actively enjoyed it.

This answer seems a duplicate of the accepted answer by @jillagre, but I aim to show that the nonequivalence may hold even when using adjectives which the OP gave examples of.

Answer (score 2):

To add to James' answer on the word "happy", note that "really unhappy" is different from "not really happy", and although "not" in the second phrase modifies "really", one might be tempted to use that phrase if one tries to avoid the "un-" prefix.

Answer (score 1):

The question was about adjectives **that take un**. The question is not about negative prefixes in general. However, I have given an overview below taken from a very good online site.

unpleasant = not pleasant
unbelievable = not believable [excluding the slang-ish meaning of unbelievable]
unchanged = not changed
untarnished = not tarnished
unhappy = not happy
unhinged = not hinged [as a door not being hinged, not the slang-ish meaning of unhinged]
unfriendly = not friendly

However, if the word changes as in dishonest, you can also use: not honest

dishonest = not honest
disused = not used

> Negative statements are the opposite of affirmative statements. **In
> English, one way to make negative statements is by adding negative
> prefixes to nouns, adjectives, and verbs. Here are **some** English
> negative prefixes: a-, dis-, il-, im-, in-, ir-, non-, un-.** For
> example, the prefix un- can be attached to the adjective happy to
> create the negative adjective unhappy. Or you can use the negative
> adverb not. Note that there is no difference in meaning between these
> two forms. Un- Prefix [negative prefixes](http://ocodereducation.com/english-grammar/adjectives-2/negative-prefixes-139)

More examples with other prefixes:
abnormal = not normal
disassembled= not assembled
illiterate = not literate
immaterial = not material
insensitive = not sensitive
irreverent = not reverent
non-vaccinated = not vaccinated
unappealing = not appealing

Not all words that appear to have a negative prefix actually do: irrigate, for example. [Also, from that website].

If a word like honest has a negative prefix like dishonest, you can't just change the prefix but you can always use: not honest.

For the full story, please visit the link.

Comment: Not sure about some of the examples. In "disused" and "disassembled" (but not "dishonest"), "dis-" carries the meaning "not any more" rather than "isn't and maybe never was", which is what "un-" and "not" mean in both cases. I don't know if I've heard "non-vaccinated" rather than "unvaccinated". And *technically*, "ab-" isn't a negative prefix, but one meaning "from, away from"...

Comment: @TimPederick a disused factory, a factory that is not used. A disassembled bicycle, a bicycle that is not assembled. unvaccinated an non-vaccinated would not mean the same thing.  And Reuters uses the term non-vaccinated: https://www.reuters.com/world/europe/80-new-covid-19-cases-spain-among-non-vaccinated-people-health-minister-says-2021-07-20/

Comment: Also, I didn't say ab was a negative prefix. The text I quote says: a, not ab. The bike was lying there disassembled (or not assembled) on the garage floor.

Comment: (1) They can indeed mean the same thing, but I'm pointing out a distinction between "dis-" and "not" that *may* be important. Per Oxford/Google: disused, no longer being used; disassemble, take something to pieces. It *was* used/assembled, now it's not. "Not" is broader, including this and the "never was" case, so it may not be "safe" (in the asker's terms). (2) *I* hadn't heard "non-vaccinated", so thanks for the citation. But why do you say "un/non-vaccinated" would *not* mean the same thing? (3) "Ab-" appears in your "abnormal". But pointing it out is just me being nitpicky. :-)

Comment: @TimPederick Where does it say that **negative prefixes** all have to mean the same thing? Oh **I did say** abnormal. Well, abnormal is not normal. So it is a negative prefix in that term, which I now remember is why I put it in. But let's make sure we upvote answers that don't provide an **overview**.

Comment: Nowhere. There's no rule that they have to mean the *exact* same thing. But OP asked if it's **safe** to use "not" instead of a negative prefix. The answer depends on whether the meaning of "not", the meaning of the negative prefix, and the speaker's intended meaning, all coincide in a particular case. (And "ab-": like I said, I was being nitpicky. Yes, it's *functionally* a negative in "abnormal", but that's not actually its *meaning*.)

Comment: @TimPederick He has an abnormal sense of right and wrong. - He has a sense of right and wrong that is not normal. It's actual meaning is that in English.  The LATIN prefix means away from yes. What is not normal is "away from" normal.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129096/discussion-between-tim-pederick-and-lambie).